# Change name, unless class is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment, my code

```
$(".name").text("John");
```

Changes all names on the page to John, however, it also changes all names that are blank to john as well

How can I make it so that it only changes classes that actually have names in the name field?

For the record, this is what the name field looks like with no name in it

```
<span class="name"></span>
```

Oh I think I solved it myself 
Would

```
$(".name:not(:empty)").text("John");
```

Work?

Comment: Your selector will not work when an element is empty but has whitespace e.g. `<span class="name">   </span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("span").each(function(){
  if($(this).text().trim() === ""){
   $(this).text("John")
  }
});
```

<kbd>[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/NQMwH/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but the edit I made to my code work. I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".name").filter(function(){
     return !$(this).text().trim() === "";
}).text("John");
```

Comment: Thank you, but the edit I made to my post works for me. 
Thanks for your time though, it is appreciated